# Numpy is not setting properly nan values: arr[arr== 0] = np.nan

Tags: python, numpy, satellite, nodata, normalize

I am creating a script to normalize a satellite scene.
My input image is of type float32, and no NoData value is assigned. However, during the normalization, I want to avoid using pixels with a value of 0 (usual black borders in the scene). To do that, I do the following for each band: *current_band[current_band == 0] = np.nan*, but this assigns nan values to all pixels instead of only those with 0.

I want to avoid setting the NoData value = 0 to the input file to avoid the output file inheriting that property. And even if I set it, numpy it is not considering it.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Here you are my code:

```
import numpy as np
import rasterio
import argparse

# TODO: implement check if file is float32

def normBands(input_raster, output_raster):
    with rasterio.open(input_raster) as src:
        # Read the number of bands and the dimensions of the image
        num_bands = src.count
        height = src.height
        width = src.width
        print(src.nodata) # this should print None

        # Create an empty array to store the normalized bands
        norm_bands = np.empty((num_bands, height, width), dtype=np.float32)
        norm_bands[:] = np.nan

        # Loop over all the bands
        for band in range(num_bands):
            # Read the current band
            current_band = src.read(band + 1)
            current_band[current_band == 0] = np.nan #NOT WORKING, makes all pixels as nan

            # Calculate mean and std for the current band
            mean = np.mean(current_band)
            std = np.std(current_band)
            print("band: "+ str(band+1))
            print(mean) ## smth NOT WORKING, prints nan!!!
            print(std)  ## smth NOT WORKING, prints nan!!!

            # Normalize the current band mean and std
            norm_band = (current_band - mean)/std

            # Add the normalized band to the array of normalized bands
            norm_bands[band, :, :] = norm_band

        # Save the normalized image
        with rasterio.open(output_raster, 'w', **src.profile) as dst:
            dst.write(norm_bands)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    aparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description='normalize bands'
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--input-raster',
        default=None
    )
    aparser.add_argument(
        '--output-raster',
        default=None
    )
    args = aparser.parse_args()
    normBands(args.input_raster, args.output_raster)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your arrays are not all nan.

It prints `nan` because that is how `np.mean` and `np.std` work, if the array contains any nans, the result will be nan.

You can use [nanmean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) and [nanstd](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanstd.html) instead:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, np.nan],
              [np.nan, 6, np.nan],
              [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]])

print(np.mean(a))
#nan

print(np.nanmean(a))
#3.5

print(np.std(a))
#nan

print(np.nanstd(a))
#1.707825127659933
```